# Overrun place locked in Dead of winter?

Tags: dead-of-winter

What happens if a location is overrun. Can you go back to the location or is it closed forever since it is filled with zombies?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When zombies overrun a location each zombie that overruns kills a survivor that is at the location. What the means is that even if all the places for zombies are filled you can still go back there to try and do something but unless you kill some zombies any that get added will kill the survivors at the location.

[Rules](http://www.plaidhatgames.com/images/games/dead-of-winter/rules.pdf)

> Whenever adding zombies, they are added 1 at a time until
>   all zombies that need to be added have been added.
>   When adding zombies to the colony, always place the first
>   zombie on any empty space in entrance 1, the second zombie
>   on any empty space in entrance 2, the third zombie on any
>   empty space in entrance 3, etc. until all of the zombies that
>   need to be added have been placed. When adding a seventh
>   zombie, place it on any empty space in entrance 1 again, an
>   eighth zombie on any empty space in entrance 2, etc. If there
>   are no empty entrance spaces in the entrance the zombie
>   would be placed but there is a barricade token in one of
>   those spaces, destroy that barricade token and remove the
>   zombie that would have been placed. If there are no empty
>   spaces and no barricade tokens, the entrance has been
>   overrun, remove that zombie and kill the survivor at the
>   colony that has the lowest influence value. If there are only
>   helpless survivors at the colony, kill a helpless survivor. If
>   there are no survivors at the colony remove the zombie that
>   would have been placed without further effect. Every time a
>   survivor is killed (including a helpless survivor), decrease
>   morale by 1. When adding zombies to non-colony locations
>   follow all of the same rules, except there is only 1 entrance to
>   place zombies in so all of the zombies are placed in spaces at
>   that entrance. See Example: Adding Zombies to right.
>   In the rare case that players ever have to
>   add zombies and there are no more zombie
>   standees left, use the zombie tokens included
>   in the game to add the additional zombies

Answer (score 0):

The location is not closed. The survivor places on any given location are different form the zombie places. If the zombies places are filled you can still move a survivor to that location. However if no zombie spaces are emptied during that round when adding a new zombie that survivor will die when the area is overrun again.